# how can I use babel polyfill to support all IE11 issues with gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, internet-explorer-11, babeljs, polyfills

I've been piecing together support for IE11 by adding plugins for `transform-object-assign` and `array-includes` and now I'm getting a symbol error for using `for of` loops. Instead of just tackling them one at a time, is it possible for me to work babel polyfill into my build below and future proof it?

I've read several related questions but still am not clear on how I'd fit babel-polyfill into the gulp build below:

```
return gulp.src(input)  // Grab the input files
        .pipe($.babel({
            presets: ['es2015'], // transform ES6 to ES5 with Babel
            plugins: ['transform-object-assign','array-includes']

        }))
        .pipe($.concat(outputFile))
        .pipe($.uglify({
            compress: {
                drop_debugger:  true
            }
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.output))  // Output file destination
        .pipe($.connect.reload());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**

I noticed an issue with babel-polyfill and IE, when i reverted to this npm package "babel-polyfill": "6.5.0" everything started working normally

**/Edit**

Are you using browserify? Also you'll need the `babel-polyfill` and the plugin `['transform-es2015-classes', { loose: true }]]`

heres my gulp task for IE compatibility with babel6:

```
gulp.task('compile', () => {
    browserify('./js/script.js', { debug: true })
    .add(require.resolve('babel-polyfill'))
    .transform(babelify.configure({presets: ['es2015'], plugins:['transform-es2015-classes', { loose: true }]]}))
    .bundle()
    .on('error', util.log.bind(util, 'Browserify Error'))
    .pipe(source('script.js'))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
    .pipe(uglify({ mangle: false }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'));
  });
```

Comment: will the `transform-es2015-classes` cover the `for..of` symbol error? Is browserify necessary?

Comment: i believe its useful for bundling it with the polyfill and using import statements

Comment: heres the webpack equivalent: https://gist.github.com/glued/e600aec12968c3fec7cb7d95d1dbb74e