# Missing module exports in IE11/Edge

Tags: javascript, node.js, internet-explorer, npm

I'm having trouble getting an npm module to work since it was changed to ES2015.

I have an ES2015 app that is bundled by browserify and transformed with babelify. I am trying to upgrade an npm module named credit-card for credit card validation, which was changed from ES5 to ES6 in the current version. The problem starts with IE11/Edge. The code works fine on Chrome. Here's how the module is imported in the transformed app (babel'd code):

```
var _this = this;

var _creditCard = require('credit-card');

var _creditCard2 = _interopRequireDefault(_creditCard);
```

Here's a piece of code calling it:

```
this.validateCreditCard = function () {
  var ccNumber = _this.account_number_credit_card.value.replace(/\D/,     '');
  _this.creditCardValidation = {
    accountHolder:     _this.account_holder_credit_card.value.replace(/\W/g, '').length >= 2,
    cvc: _this.account_cvc_credit_card.value.replace(/\D/g, '').length     > 2,
    accountNumber: _creditCard2.default.isValidCardNumber(ccNumber,     _creditCard2.default.determineCardType(ccNumber, { allowPartial: true }))
  };
  return _underscore2.default.all(_underscore2.default.values(_this.creditCardValida    tion));
};
```

Now on Chrome this works without a problem. On IE however, the exported functions of the credit card module are missing.

[Here's a printscreen of a console log of the module in IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvZZV.png)

[And here's Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sg7IK.png)

It looks like defaults is completely missing in IE. Is this a known issue? Do any of you have encountered this problem before and can give me some hints? Any pointers on how I could investigate this issue to understand what is going wrong and how I could fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Stepping through the `require()` in IE11 Debugger i found out that there was a problem with `Object.assign` being `undefined` in IE11. After some searching I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36264993/how-can-i-use-babel-polyfill-to-support-all-ie11-issues-with-gulp). The answer in this thread worked out in the end. I needed to add polyfill to my browserify bundle and enable the `"transform-es2015-classes"` plugin with the opt `loose: true` (See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36264993/how-can-i-use-babel-polyfill-to-support-all-ie11-issues-with-gulp) for code).